# how to read\print args in bash script with a login

Tags: bash

given a bash script named `foo.sh` that performs [a login](https://manpages.org/bash#options)

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash -l

bar() {
 echo "$@"
}

bar "$@"
```

although `foo.sh` is invoked with arguments, the arguments are not being printed.
how to print the arguments that are passed to `foo.sh`? e.g.

```bash
$ ./foo.sh arg1 arg2
```

i would expect to get the output

```bash
arg1 arg2
```

Comment: Try `"$@"`, not `"@$"`. For specific arguments, you can use the index (e.g. `$1`), where it will include the script's execution path as the first argument. Given your edit, you should show your expected output and what you're actually getting, as the edit now should work. You may want `-e` for `echo` to interpret special characters (e.g. `\n`). `printf` tends to be more friendly for shell output.

Comment: @Rogue Thanks for the clarification. Made another edit.

Comment: Which version of bash is this? how to you invoke the script?

Comment: What's your actual output? Why is the shebang line `/usr/bin/env bash -l` instead of `/usr/bin/bash` or some other direct reference (in your words)?

Comment: @Jetchisel 5.2.15

Comment: @Rogue there is a login to has the bash profile loaded before execution

Comment: Your shebang means `/usr/bin/env 'bash -l'`, so the script will fail if invoked as `./script.sh` instead of `bash script.sh`

Comment: @Fravadona please clarify

Comment: a shebang is split on the first space character into `command argument`; so your `#!/usr/bin/env bash -l` is equivalent to run `/usr/bin/env "bash -l"` from the command line, which results in `/usr/bin/env: bash -l: No such file or directory`

Comment: @Fravadona that's not correct. appending `-x` to `-l` shoes the opposite.

Comment: @Fravadona that depends on the system, and kernel version and shell version, whichever will parse it. Different shells and different kernels parse shebang differently. Which: @Mr. What shell, shell version, operating system, kernel version are you running? `i would expect to get the output` What output are you getting instead? `appending -x to -l` what is the output of the script with appended `-x`? Does it work when running `bash ./foo.sh arg1 arg2`? Does it work when removing `-l`? Does it work with `#!/bin/bash` shebang?

Answer (score 2):

If you have a recent `/usr/bin/env` which accept `-S (--split-string)` option :

```
#!/usr/bin/env -S bash -l

bar() {
 echo "$@"
}

bar "$@"
```